# How to apply margins or css classes to Angular 2 component?

Tags: css, angular

Suppose I have a component that I want to apply some margins to, preferably via Bootstrap helper classes, e.g. mt-3 to apply top margin. When I specify them on the component like this:

```
<my-custom-input 
   required 
   class="mt-3" 
   name="usr" 
   label="User" 
   placeholder="Please enter username" 
   [(ngModel)]="username">
</my-custom-input>
```

the `class="mt-3"` does not do anything! Setting the margin manually via Chrome dev tools is not possible either... I'm guessing because `my-custom-input` is not a predefined HTML element (like `div`), it cannot have defined margins?

This seems incredibly trivial thing to need in any application, but I'm surprised I was unable to find an answer thus far. How do we reposition such component? At the very least, specifying margins at the parent level (not inside components template) seems crucial thing to need?..

Comment: What your my-custom-input do with the class? 
There are more HTML elements inside my-custom-input?

Comment: @EyalCohen Yes `my-custom-input` does have a div and more nested content inside that div.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Give it a `display: block;` in your css :

```css
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It looks like we need to set `display` property to host element. Also looks like `display: flex` works. It will be useful if someone can explain why this needs to be done

Comment: this answer should have more votes. It took me days to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Bootstrap installed in your Angular project !
It proposes these dynamic properties for you !